# Can you merge two Flux, without blocking, such that the result only contains unique elements?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is there a way to merge two Flux such that the result only contains unique elements? I can block on the output and then convert it to a set, but is there a way that does *not* depend on blocking?

Source (Kotlin)

```
val set1 = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val set2 = Flux.just(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)

val mergedSet = set1.mergeWith(set2)

println(mergedSet.collectList().block())
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Desired Output (order is not important)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: You can use [distinct](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#distinct--) operator after you merged two streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Flux's [merge](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-) method and then apply [`distinct()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#distinct--) to it.

```
Flux.merge (Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Flux.just(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)).distinct();
```

This way you get a flux which produces only distinct values.